# Error in migration, module not found error in Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I tried to create a custom user model, so I extended AbstractBaseUser and BaseUserManager for model management.

The error that I've got when I tried to migrate or run server is:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/media/amir/Development/Dev/blog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/amir/Development/Dev/blog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/media/amir/Development/Dev/blog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/media/amir/Development/Dev/blog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/media/amir/Development/Dev/blog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/amir/Development/Dev/blog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/media/amir/Development/Dev/blog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/media/amir/Development/Dev/blog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.messagesdjango'
```

My custom user model is:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
        email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=100, unique=True)
        name = models.CharField(verbose_name="full name", max_length=100)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
        last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
        USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username", "name"]
    
        objects = MyAccountManager()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
    
        def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            return self.is_admin
        
        def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
            return True
```

and the model manager is:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username")
        
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=self.username,
            name=self.name
        )
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, name):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username")
        
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=self.username,
            name=self.name,
            password=password
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

I think the error might be for incompatibility of Python 3.8 and Django 3.1 which I've installed in my venv:

**pip list:**

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
asgiref             3.2.10
Django              3.1.1
djangorestframework 3.11.1
pip                 20.2.3
psycopg2            2.8.6
pytz                2020.1
setuptools          50.3.0
sqlparse            0.3.1
```

Comment: How does your `INSTALLED_APPS` looks like? You are either missing a comma after `django.contrib.messages` or you accidentally copy-pasted there something.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Wow, how simple it was :)). answer and let me accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your `INSTALLED_APPS` looks like? You are either missing a comma after `django.contrib.messages` or you accidentally copy-pasted there something.